# UIView within a container view not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I couldn't get the blue rectangle view to show. IT is currently the subview of the grey view and has vertical/horizontal constraints. I don't have enough "reputations" to post images so heres the link to the screenshot: http://imgur.com/gallery/KCFA1O6/new

Thanks.

Comment: apply the constraints to the blue rect according to the grey view . or Apply the top constraint according to label"Hour" and bottom to label "00" and align it centre to the label

Comment: I had constraints (Alight X, Alight Y) I even added a bunch of others, still didn't work

Comment: align X and Y according to what ? align X and Y according to the Inside labels . or try it reset to suggested constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is Set the label ":" in centre vertical and horizontally and align all the constraints according to it . align the blue view giving it top , height , width and centre X to the label ":" and all other views giving them top and align centre X to the label ":" as this

All the applied constraints are in the image you can get help from here

[image]

/// ******************//

in same the way i change the orientation of the device  as [image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I actually did align it to the ":" , and to the superview, which is the grey view, (and separately, i.e. only to the ":), it still not working : http://i.imgur.com/xUengGA.png

Comment: woo this much constraints  remove all and only add height and width and then give it Top to the grey view and Centre X to ":" only 4 constraints only remove all other

Comment: Problem solved: turns out, I set the border in my `init(_:frame)` instead of the `init(_:coder)`, this whole initializer thing is till kind of confusing to me, I'm because in Apple's documentation it says "it is recommended that I implement `initWithFrame`". But otherwise, thanks for your help